# Implementing custom Options in Adobe AEM HTL (formerly known as Sightly)?

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

This question is about Options, a feature in Adobe's proprietary language `HTL`:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/expression-language.html
- [Expression Option Sightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583326/expression-option-sightly)

My simple question: Can I extend HTL by implementing my own custom Options? If so, how?

Comment: If you have a specific requirement you are trying to implement, please list it. There might be a better option that extending HTL options.

Comment: The possible requirements are too many too list, but the one I had in mind when I asked the question 4 days ago, is that I would like to re-implement the `extension` option correctly (making it content aware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can implement your own custom options for an HTL expression. You will need to implement a [Filter](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly-compiler/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/filter/Filter.java) and add it to the [compiler](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly-compiler/blob/b977da8c899c202ab2cceb96d8d724dcc53b4b0a/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/compiler/SightlyCompiler.java#L107).

But you shouldn't, as:

1. This is not a designed extension point. You will need to fork the implementation and modify it, thus becoming responsible for keeping it up-to-date further down the road.
2. You can most probably get the same results by using the public APIs (such as https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#221-use).
3. In case you think there's a very good reason for adding or modifying expression options, you can propose an HTL specification change (and also contribute the implementation in Sling).

Answer (score 1):

No. To implement custom options you will have to extend the respective [plugin](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly-compiler/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/plugin) that supports that expression. those classes are not exported by sightly scripting compiler bundle and are not available to be customized.